# Mock a function that expects an implicit conversion to a generic type

Tags: scala, mockito, scala-cats

I'm attempting to mock a generic method using Mockito. The method I'm trying to mock creates a `ReaderT` over the generic type `T`, and expects  that an implicit conversion is also made available to convert the `Output` type to the generic type `T` supplied.

The implementation isn't important, but here's a reduction of the method itself:

```
/**
 * The return type of WebReaderT is held within the class scope.
 * It pre-populates some of the types for ReaderT.
 */
def createToken[T](authRequest: Input, tokenTtl: TokenTtlConfig)(implicit f: Output => T): WebReaderT[T]
```

The method works as I expect it to when running the API, however, I'm receiving an error when mocking and then executing it within my tests. I've gone through a few iterations of the mock and this is what I currently have:

```
when(mock.createToken[Any](any[AuthAdapter.Input], any[TokenTtlConfig])(any[AuthAdapter.Output => Any])) thenAnswer { invocation =>
  val tokenTtl = invocation.getArgument[TokenTtlConfig](1)

  tokenTtl match {
    case config.tokenTtlMap.v0Tokens => mockCreateToken[LoginResponse](tokenTtl)
    case config.tokenTtlMap.v1Tokens => mockCreateToken[AccessTokenResponse](tokenTtl)
  }
}

/**
 * This method is functionally a direct copy of the method that
 * it's effectively mocking.
 */
def mockCreateToken[T](tokenTtl: TokenTtlConfig)(implicit f: AuthAdapter.Output => T): WebReaderT[T] = {
  ReaderT.lift[EitherTError, SentinelEnv[Future], T](EitherT.fromEither[Future](Right(AuthAdapter.Output(
    mockUser1._id,
    mockUser1._id,
    tokenTtl.accessTtl.map(AccessToken(DateTime.now, _, "foo")),
    tokenTtl.refreshTtl.map(RefreshToken(DateTime.now, _, "bar"))
  ))))
}
```

Because I'm unable to have a wildcard type of, say, `T` in the mock itself (from my knowledge), I have to match against `Any` and then determine the expected output type by matching the `tokenTtl` to a set of known values. This is obviously a pretty dubious way for me to determine the output type, as it relies heavily on the applications current use of the `config.tokenTtlMap.<?>` values internally.

To avoid this poor approach I'd hoped that Mockito was capable of matching the types passed to generic methods like this:

```
// Only match "LoginResponse"
when(mockAuthAdapter.createToken[LoginResponse](any[AuthAdapter.Input], any[TokenTtlConfig])(any[AuthAdapter.Output => LoginResponse])) thenAnswer { invocation =>
  mockCreateToken[LoginResponse](invocation.getArgument[TokenTtlConfig](1))
}

// Only match "AccessTokenResponse"
when(mockAuthAdapter.createToken[AccessTokenResponse](any[AuthAdapter.Input], any[TokenTtlConfig])(any[AuthAdapter.Output => AccessTokenResponse])) thenAnswer { invocation =>
  mockCreateToken[AccessTokenResponse](invocation.getArgument[TokenTtlConfig](1))
}
```

This mock implementation is clearly the best way to go, but as far as I can tell, Mockito simply ignores the first mock (does the second override it?), and therefore doesn't correctly match the expected output types passed to the generic method.

Despite my best efforts, both implementations lead to a `NullPointerException` like this:

```
[ERROR] [12/13/2017 14:42:05.587] [specs2.fixed.env-1062542254-1] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(io-ctek-services-sentinel-routes-v0-TokensRouteSpec)] Error during processing of request: 'java.lang.NullPointerException (No error message supplied)'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cats.data.EitherTFunctions$FromEitherPartiallyApplied.apply(EitherT.scala:277)
    at io.ctek.services.sentinel.helpers.RouteHelpers$.createToken(RouteHelpers.scala:49)
    at io.ctek.services.sentinel.helpers.RouteHelpers$.$anonfun$new$1(RouteHelpers.scala:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.StubbedInvocationMatcher.answer(StubbedInvocationMatcher.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:95)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:36)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor.doIntercept(MockMethodInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefaultingToRealMethod.interceptSuperCallable(MockMethodInterceptor.java:119)
```

> The full error can be found at this [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/p41HBwwk)

I'd greatly appreciate any help in solving this issue!

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting a wall with name: "Type erasure". Mockito operates purely at runtime when no information about generics is maintained. There are ways to deal with this problem in scala in most cases using `ClassTag` or `TypeTag`, but i doubt it can be easly solved in the case of mockito. 
There is the following problem:

Mockito registers mock at runtime, using stack of method invocation, so any workaround of type erasure would need to pass those aditional implicits directly, consider the following:

```
def myMethod[A](argument: Input): Output
//in tests
when(mock.myMethod[Int](any[Input])) thanAnswer {???}
when(mock.myMethod[Int](any[Input])) thanAnswer {???}
```

Second definition overrides first as you have correctly observed. So we can try to fix this problem, by using ClassTags:

```
def myMethod[A:ClassTag](argument: Input): Output
//in tests
when(mock.myMethod[Int](any[Input])) thanAnswer {???}
when(mock.myMethod[Double](any[Input])) thanAnswer {???}
```

What about implicit class tag argument now? First, i am not sure how mockito will interact with it. Second, you are polluting your method signature with unnecessary implicit argument only because it is needed to write test.

You may try to use some scala specific solution like [scala mock](http://scalamock.org/user-guide/matching/).